# Would method of ingesting coffee affect its effectiveness in terms of caffeine extraction to the body?

Tags: ground-coffee, caffeine

I have some instant coffee powder packs that include coffee, milk, and sugar in a single packet.
Lately, due to circumstances related to limited time and availability of electricity, I've been ingesting them by gradually swallowing the powder after dissolving it in my mouth with saliva (a bit at a time), and then later drinking some cold water.

In terms of the body extracting the caffeine from this powder, is there a way to know if this means of ingestion is more efficient/effective than the normal means (i.e.: mixing powder with boiled water and then drinking)?

Comment: If your question really is "is there a way", then yes. You measure the caffeine content in your blood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have cited sources, but from experience (the next best thing), it seems that ingesting the instant coffee powder and then drinking water later was about as effective as mixing the powder with hot water.

Additionally, it was found that breathing a steady supply of fresh air also increases the effectiveness of the caffeine extraction since oxygen boosts the body's metabolism.